# how can i get rid of quotation marks in python print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need the print were words in my list are separated with space, but the result of my print is as follows
['Salt']

So it prints it as list with quotations :(

sry code is in Finnish :S

```
def poistaTuote(Tuotteet):
    print("Ostoslistassasi on " + str(len(Tuotteet)) + " tuotetta.")
    Index = int(input("Anna poistettavan tuotteen järjestysnumero: "))
    Index = (Index)-1
    for i in range(len(Tuotteet)):
        if (Index == Tuotteet[i].index):
            Index = i
    if (Index == -1):
        print("Indeksiä " + str(Index) + " ei löydy.")
        print("Tuotteiden järjestysnumerot alkavat numerosta 1.")
    else:
        del Tuotteet[Index]
        print("\nOstoslistasi sisältää seuraavat tuotteet:")
        print(Tuotteet, end = " ")
    return Tuotteet
```

Current output:

Ostoslistasi sisältää seuraavat tuotteet:
['Leipä', ' Leivän päälliset']

Desired output
Leipä Leivän päälliset

Comment: I am not sure I am getting your problem. What is the expected print? What does it print instead? There are lots of prints in your code, which is the problematic one?

Comment: print(Tuotteet, end = " ")

Comment: The print should come without those quotation marks

Comment: [' '] those marks shouldn't be there at the result; The result should be with space between words in my list i created - Milk Salt

Comment: You should show a clear example of the input, current output, and desired output so people don't have to guess what you mean.

Comment: FYI, learn about f-strings:  `print("Ostoslistassasi on " + str(len(Tuotteet)) + " tuotetta.")` can be `print(f"Ostoslistassasi on {len(Tuotteet)} tuotetta.")`

Comment: the code itself is too long to copy there :S

Comment: Consider the [mcve] guidelines.  All you need for this question is a fixed value of `Tuotteet` such as `Tuotteet = ['Bread']` and `print(Tuotteet)` with result `['Bread']`.  You want `Bread`.  The rest of the code and output is not needed to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: `print(*Tuotteet, sep=" ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spread the list elements as separate arguments to `print`:

```
print(*Tuotteet)
```

Or use `str.join`:

```
print(" ".join(Tuotteet))
```

Comment: Yessss :) it worked ... the only problem with our teacher :) command join might be not allowed :) we just started to learn a month ago and doing things long way ...

Comment: In that case you might want to try something like `for word in Tuotteet: ...`

Comment: I am trying to guess how you found the solution, by trying to understand what `Tuotteet` is. Both `Tuotteet = ['a','b']` and `Tuotteet = ['ab']` print nicely with `print(*Tuotteet)` so what is `Tuotteet` that gives the wrong output?

Comment: @Fra93 the contents are evident by the output given in the question: `['Leipä', ' Leivän päälliset']`.